# How to display all values of x (categorical) when plotting y (integer) with Python

Tags: python, plot

[image]

Hello,

I would like to plot `Total_Minutes` given the `MDL_AVI` categorical variable. So I calculate means, using:

```
mean=data.groupby('MDL_AVI').mean().dropna()
```

However, when plotting, only some of the values of `MDL_AVI` are displayed (see the image). How can I display the name of all the categories on the axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [plt.xticks()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks),

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.xticks(locations, labels)
```

Comment: At first it didn't work because I executed my code row by row (on Spyder) but then when executing all the lines together (xticks & plot) it worked just perfect. Thank you!